# Error : "unexpected input in.." when trying to read csv file with read.csv()

Tags: r

I am trying to read a csv file into R but I am always getting the same error message

```
 Error: unexpected input in "read.csv(C:\"...
```

Here is my code :

```
read.csv(C:\Users\hp\Documents\dataset_self_reports_of height., header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: When using backslashes, you need to double them or use forward slashes: `"C:\\Users\\hp\\Documents\\dataset_self_reports_of height"` or `"C:/Users/hp/Documents/dataset_self_reports_of height"`. And use quotes, as Gainz mentions.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `file` argument is suppose to be a character string.

You actually have

`C:\Users\hp\Documents\dataset_self_reports_of height`

When it's suppose to be

`"C:/Users/hp/Documents/dataset_self_reports_of height"`

Also in R `\` need to be use this way `/`.

**So you should most likely use it this way :**

`read.csv("C:/Users/hp/Documents/dataset_self_reports_of height", header = TRUE, sep = ",")`

I suggest you read a few R  tutorials to know how R works.